# how to get values from *.dbl/*.mt4

Tags: java, kotlin, inputstream, fileinputstream, oscilloscope

I received data from the oscilloscope in 64-bit doubles (*.dbl) or in "measured data" (*.mt4) format. How can I parse it (preferably Java or Kotlin) or where can I find documentation for this format?

I tried using DataInputStream.readDouble but the results were weird

c5 12 52 9b ec 3f 12 c0 17 29 e9 87 4e 71 12 c0 6a 3f 80 74
b0 a2 12 c0 b8 39 8e 9e b1 37 12 c0 17 29 e9 87 4e 71 12 c0
c5 12 52 9b ec 3f 12 c0 4e 8d f8 7a 3a 92 12 c0 aa 60 ca a1

Comment: That doesn't sound like a standard file format, we would probably need to know which oscilloscope this is and get related documentation to that. A sample of the file could also prove helpful

Comment: I don't have an app. A friend sent me a file. There are several formats, now I looked, there is an option *.mt4

Comment: Maybe your friend can give you enough information about the oscilloscope so that you can find out how to parse the file.

Comment: Why not post a link to the file?

Comment: Can you edit the question with first 20 bytes or so (`print(list(open('filename', 'rb').read(20)))` in python). I'd rather not be opening random files from dropbox.

Comment: So how did the "weird" stuff manifest itself? If that's a file of 64 bit values, it could be big-endian *or* little-endian

Comment: First eight values as doubles, little-endian: `-4.56, -4.61, -4.66, -4.55, -4.61, -4.56, -4.64, -4.55` Big-endian ones are *crazy* ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read it with this. The values are in line with your expectations:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import static java.nio.ByteOrder.*;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class Doubler {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int count = -1;
        byte[] buff = new byte[8];
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(8).order(LITTLE_ENDIAN);
        try (InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(Path.of(args[0]))) {
            while ((count = in.read(buff)) > -1) {
                bb.put(buff);
                bb.rewind();
                System.out.printf("%.2f%n", bb.getDouble());
                bb.rewind();
            }
        }
    }
}
```